# Retrieve keys from Authorization keys function level authorization in Azure using C#

Tags: c#, azure, key-management

I need to get the keys through code, not through a portal. For doing this I have found REST API in Google.
This is the link to [Azure Key management API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API), but do this we need to do an authentication.

We have to develop all this using C# only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code.

```
 #install Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent and Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent    
string clientId = "client id";
     string secret = "secret key";
     string tenant = "tenant id";
     var functionName ="functionName";
     var webFunctionAppName = "functionApp name";
     string resourceGroup = "resource group name";
     var credentials = new AzureCredentials(new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = secret}, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
     var azure = Azure
              .Configure()
              .Authenticate(credentials)
              .WithDefaultSubscription();

     var webFunctionApp = azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, webFunctionAppName);
     var ftpUsername = webFunctionApp.GetPublishingProfile().FtpUsername;
     var username = ftpUsername.Split('\\').ToList()[1];
     var password = webFunctionApp.GetPublishingProfile().FtpPassword;
     var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
     var apiUrl = new Uri($"https://{webFunctionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api");
     var siteUrl = new Uri($"https://{webFunctionAppName}.azurewebsites.net");
     string JWT;
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {base64Auth}");

         var result = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/functions/admin/token").Result;
         JWT = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim('"'); //get  JWT for call funtion key
       }
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWT);
        var key = client.GetAsync($"{siteUrl}/admin/functions/{functionName}/keys").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      }
```

Besides, you also can refer to the [document](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11e2840d-4f12-40f8-aaf4-f306dc799a83/azure-function-key-management-api?forum=AzureFunctions).

Comment: The client '9671c613-52b4-42d4-b260-6fa0c7ab6bff' with object id '9671c613-52b4-42d4-b260-6fa0c7ab6bff' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over scope '/subscriptions/1ab4f7c1-3d23-419b-9d6c-cae2423ca16d/resourceGroups/conceptone/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/imsfap'.

Comment: Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: string clientId = "8e636aed-a0c6-47a1-af77-137f96e262b8";
string secret = "g5sL6PDyNY4a65Ely7pXXpO/UqUwVvIKBEaTTdEuRY4=";
string tenant = "2d4d44fe-dba2-49bc-8447-2f0602a1bfe1";
var functionName = "Ims";
var webFunctionAppName = "imsfap";
string resourceGroup = "conceptone"; string SubscriptionId = "1ab4f7c1-3d23-419b-9d6c-cae2423ca16d";

these are parameters i have passed

Comment: The same code  what u have provided the same one i have used

Comment: Have you assigned a  role to your account? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#azure-rbac-roles.